# incorrect syntax error while executing from java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

i have a stored proce(that Stored proc accept 1  parameter ) i am executing that from java.

for that stored proc we are sending the parameter param1

here the

```
 param1 = "(''parent''),(''child'')"; //added double single quotes for sql server
```

//acutal value is

```
 param1 =  "('parent'), ('child')";
```

it's showing below error

**Incorrect syntax near 'PARENT00005'.'**

When I manually execute the statement in MS SQLServer Management Studio it is accepted.

Comment: Can you show the SQL and Java code to execute the stored procedure?

Comment: Include in your question 1) the declaration of the stored procedure (not the fully body) 2) Relevant portions of your code where you are constructing your query and executing it. 3) The error stacktrace that is being created.